# IFloatingPoint missing ReadSignificandLittleEndian and other readers

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, .net-generic-math

I don't understand how that is possible and cannot believe that it is true. There are methods for writing the value as byte array like WriteSignificandLittleEndian but there is no method for reading it like ReadSignificandLittleEndian. So, what's good in writing then. Maybe it is hidden somewhere too deep but all my tries to find it failed. Can somebody confirm that they are missing or tell me how to read what was written with methods like WriteSignificandLittleEndian?